# Livewire3 - The index is not updated in the loop

Tags: php, laravel

Can I please ask why the $index variable inside the "item" component is not updated if I change their order?

```php
<div>
    @foreach($array as $index => $item)
        <livewire:item wire:key="{{$item}}" :$item :$index />
    @endforeach
</div>
```

When first rendered, the parent and child $index match.

[image: Before]

After moving the element down, the index is correctly overwritten for the parent but remains for the child.

[image: after]

I've also asked on the official livewire help, but no one is replying there.